# Getting XMLHttpRequest while also receiving the response body

Tags: angular, http, xmlhttprequest, cors, observable

**Update:** Although I setup CORS on the AWS API Gateway api, I'm using the Lambda Proxy configuration and that requires that I put the needed headers in the Lambda handler.

I can't figure this one out. I'm getting the CORS error while, at the same time, getting a response body (the actual expected response). I'm using angular2/http.

[image]

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/search. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Any idea how that's even possible??

Code (the error is always caught and printed out, while I still get the appropriate response):

```
  public getNotes(searchString: string, authtoken: string): Observable<NotesResponse> {
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    headers.append('Authorization', authtoken);
    headers.append('search-key', searchString);

    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http.post(this.notesUrl, null, options) // ...using post request
      .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); //...errors if
  }

this.com.notesService.getNotes(this.com.searchQuery, result).subscribe(
  notes => {
    console.log("Notes: notes");
  },
  err => {
    // Log errors if any
    console.log("There was an error retrieving the notes: " + err);
  });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/42744707#42744707

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. I'm getting the actual response json, but at the same time I get the CORS exception. If it was just a CORS issue I wouldn't be able to do a post on the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser gets the response and can access it, which is why it can show it in devtools. The reason you can’t get to it from your code is, the browser doesn’t let your code access it—because the server isn’t sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header to tell the browser to allow client-side JavaScript code to access responses from it cross-origin.

CORS doesn’t block servers from sending responses back to browsers. Servers send responses back regardless, and browsers receive them regardless. But just because the browser has received the response doesn’t mean the browser will expose it to your client code. Browsers will only expose cross-origin responses to your code if they include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: You were right. Although I setup CORS on the AWS API Gateway api, I'm using the Lambda Proxy configuration and that requires that I put the needed headers in the Lambda handler, since the API Gateway headers are basically ignored. Your post made me look harder. Thanks! :)